# Turn SSLchecking off in M2Crypto in Python

Tags: python, ssl, soappy

Is there a way to turn off SSL checking so that WrongHost Exceptions are not generated when using SOAPpy in python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable all peer certificate checks in M2Crypto like that:

```
from M2Crypto import SSL, httpslib

context = SSL.Context("sslv3")

# Disable certificate checking
context.set_verify(0, depth = 0)

connection = httpslib.HTTPSConnection("somehostname", 443, ssl_context=context)

# Hack (!!!) for disabling host name check <CN> == <expected host name>.
# Will affect any future SSL connections made by M2Crypto!
SSL.Connection.postConnectionCheck = None

connection.connect() # <-- this would normally raise SSL verification errors
connection.request("GET", "/")

...
```

I hope you're aware that this will essentially **disable** security for any SSL connection created with M2Crypto. So this isn't recommendable at all, except if you're only communicating with one server and think that the man-in-the-middle risk is more acceptable than having unencrypted HTTP.

So far for the M2Crypto solution, but as your question (as opposed to your title) asks for SOAPpy (which I haven't used yet), the solution might be different because the [SOAPpy config](http://pywebsvcs.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pywebsvcs/trunk/SOAPpy/SOAPpy/Config.py?view=markup) seems to use the `socket` module instead of `M2Crypto.SSL` (see line 132). I don't know how to prevent the `socket.ssl` module to check host names.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on AndiDog's answer, you can set postConnectionCheck on a instance-by-instance basis and in version 0.21.1 (at least) of M2Crypto, there is the `Connect.set_post_connection_check_callback()` method to do so:

```
sslsock = M2Crypto.SSL.Connection(sslcontext)
# Disable checking of server certificates
sslsock.set_post_connection_check_callback(None)
```

Note that disables both checking of connected to servers and accepted clients (the latter is disabled by default).

The parameter, if not None, is a function that takes a certificate and address, i.e.:

```
check(self.get_peer_cert(), self.addr[0])
```

For reference, see the [M2Crypto source](http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/M2Crypto/SSL/Connection.py).